# SQL SUM count of parents with active children

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

```
'SUM(IF(children.status > 0, 1, 0)) AS count'
```

I currently have the above code in my select statement, however it returns the count of children who are active, rather than the amount of parents who have active children. While a large portion of my data is single children elements, there are some parents who have large numbers of children who will really mess up the count. What would be the best way of counting the amount of parents who have children who have a status above 0?

The relevant fields in the tables are as defined below.

```
parent {
int id
}

children {
int id
int parent_id
int status
}
```

Comment: `SUM(children.status > 0) as count` try this code, the condition will return Boolean (0, 1) on condition match, 1 return will be sum count and you want to count children who have status above 0

Comment: can you give me the definition of your data tables, I think I know the answer but not sure

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry! The bad English is the last line of the sentence asked the wrong thing, but I've since edited it. I want the number of parents who have children whose status is above 0

Comment: you can use Case statement

Comment: @雰囲気が読めない人 show us parent db definition and how to related with children

Comment: you might not even need a case depending on his table structure

Comment: I've edited the post to show the table relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a DISTINCT to get rid of duplicates. This is using a CASE:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN children.status > 0 THEN parent_id END)
```

You could probably do the same with IF, but I prefer Standard SQL's CASE:

COUNT(DISTINCT IF(children.status > 0, parent_id, NULL))

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! I didn't know about the distinct keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM parent
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent_id
             FROM children
             WHERE status > 0);
```

I don't know how your tables are set up but something like this might work
Are parent and children different tables or same table? (to be honest doesn't really matter because this works for both but you might be able to solve it differently if you have 2 different tables)

Comment: according to what he put in his question this should work, unless he didn't give us some piece of information